# Make only links interactive in joint js

Tags: css, jointjs

I got this joint js code with some rects and links :

```
var graph = new joint.dia.Graph;
var paper = new joint.dia.Paper({
    el: $('#div1'),
    interactive: false,
    width: 1200,
    height: 1200,
    model: graph,
    gridSize: 1
});
    var rect1 = new joint.shapes.basic.Rect({
        position: { x: 80, y: y_value },
        size: { width: 30, height: 55 },
        attrs: { 
            rect: { fill: bgcolor1,'stroke-width': 0 },
            text: {
                text: 'Rect1',
                fill: 'white'
            } 
        }
    });

    var rect2 = new joint.shapes.basic.Rect({
        position: { x: 80, y: y_value + 80 },
        size: { width: 30, height: 55 },
        attrs: { 
            rect: { fill: bgcolor1,'stroke-width': 0 },
            text: {
                text: 'Rect1',
                fill: 'white'
            } 
        }
    });

    var link{{ pre }} = new joint.dia.Link({
        source: { id: rect1.id },
        target: { id: rect2.id },
        vertices: [{ x: initialx, y: syposition.y + 23 }, { x: initialx, y: typosition.y + 23 }],
    });
```

As you can see i have the paper property interactive in 'false', so user can't drag and drop any element or delete links, buttt actually want that he can drag the link vertices as he wish, how can i do it ?, wich property in joint.min.css ? or from this code is ther a way ??

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you can define `interactive` as a function, that returns `true` for links and `false` for elements. That makes links interactive while elements not.

```
var paper = new joint.dia.Paper({
  interactive: function(cellView) {
    return cellView.model.isLink();
  }
});
```

And as per documentation

> **interactive** - if set to `false`, interaction with elements and links is
>   disabled. If it is a function, it will be called with the cell view in
>   action and the name of the method it is evaluated in (*'pointerdown'*,
>   *'pointermove'*, ...). If the returned value of such a function is `false`
>   interaction will be disabled for the action. For links, there are
>   special properties of the interaction object that are useful to
>   disable the default behaviour. These properties are: `vertexAdd`,
>   `vertexMove`, `vertexRemove` and `arrowheadMove`. By setting any of these
>   properties to `false`, you can disable the related default action on
>   links.

by doing the following you can enable the vertex movement only.

```
interactive: function(cellView) {
  if (cellView.model.isLink()) {
    return {
      vertexAdd: false,
      vertexRemove: false,
      arrowheadMove: false,
      // vertexMove: true
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kumilingus/03omcuLm/